# operations to consecutive rows of a vector in R

Tags: r

I don't know how to phrase it in a better way. Here is my problem.

A very simple data frame something like --

```
 df= {"time"   "east"   "north"   
         1      0      0
         2      2      0
         3      1      0
         4      1      2 
     }
```

Now, I would like to add distance (as another column) between two consecutive time frames (except first row). For e.g at `time==2` the distance should be calculated as `sqrt( (2-0)*(2-0) + (0-0)*(0-0) )`. A probably outcome could be something like this

```
 df= {"time"   "east"   "north"  "distance"   
         1       0        0         0
         2       2        0         2
         3       1        0         1
         4       1        2         2
     }
```

Naturally, I would like to have a method to get the distance which takes east and north from two consecutive rows and return euclidean distance between the points. 
**1) How can I achieve distance between two consecutive points in a data frame?**

I want to apply similar operations or configurable functions (distance, consecutive subtraction, etc) for subsets of a huge data frames. In the end I would like to plot segments, for e.g.

```
index = length(df$time)-1
segments( df$time[index],df$time[index+1], df$distance[index], df$distance[index+1] )
```

**2) Is there a better way to plot segments from consecutive points?** A pointer for something like this will also be very useful.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Maybe if you include expected output...

Comment: thanks, I have added a probably output too.

Comment: based on your calcuation, `with(df, sqrt((east-north)^2 + (lag(east)-lag(north))^2))`, then the values will be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library( data.table )
setDT( df )[ , distance := sqrt( ( east - shift( east, 1, type = "lag", fill = 0 ) ) ^ 2 +
                        ( north - shift( north, 1, type = "lag", fill = 0 ) ) ^ 2 ) ]
```

Should achieve what you're after. The `shift` function takes a value offset by the given number of rows. `lag` means it'll look upwards (`lead` would look downwards).

I also added `fill = 0` to the `shift` calls. This specifies a value for cells where the `shift` function can't be performed (in this case, row 1). By making that zero, you're effectively specifying a "start" point of 0, so even the first row can have a distance, it'll just be from the zero point, rather than any cells above it.

Comment: I guess, I can do that same for other operations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(distance = sqrt((east - lag(east, default = 0))^2 + 
                   (north - lag(north, default = 0))^2))
#    time east north distance
#1    1    0     0        0
#2    2    2     0        2
#3    3    1     0        1
#4    4    1     2        2
```